Resharpening utility knife blades
I don't like restocking even on expendables. I like buying a few items really cheap & restoring or recycling them, as I go through them. Even on my tools, I expect them to last me a lifetime.
Anyways, one of those expendable items are utility knife blades. I bought a bunch years ago, expecting them to last me a good while. Well, now has been a good while. I don't want to buy utility blades en masse again; that it will alarm the authorities (I'm healthily paranoid).
Going forward, I'd like to keep the same blades & not snap off the tip as it gets worn out; just resharpening the blade.
What's the best knife resharpening system I could buy for this? I want the resharpened edge to have the bevel & be as sharp as when I bought the blade new.
How about those pull through sharpeners? They seem to be fast, but do they give a good edge? Please just don't suggest I do it freehand.

Consider to modify your question to remove the requirement of an opinion. "Best" is subjective and is contrary to StackExchange guidelines. Provide a specific focus rather than a subjective request. Consider also to provide the research you've performed, as there are a large number of YouTube videos regarding sharpening, which you may have overlooked.

The whole point of the utility knife is that it uses disposable blades. If you don't want disposable blades, there are other knives that work much better in nearly any application.

And "healthily paranoid" is an oxymoron. Do you honestly think that "the authorities" are tracking who purchases utility knife blades, but are NOT tracking who asks about them on line? Which do you think is easier for them to do?

shopping questions are also off topic here

there is a whole ecosystem of knife/blade sharpeners.  Way too many to label one as "best."

I have a small sharpening stone in "fine" grit size that I use to put a fresh edge on my disposable utility knives. Takes just a few seconds and works great.

That's what I have been doing for years. "Free hand"? You could call it that, it's no big deal. Sharpening a utility knife blade is really pretty trivial.  I use a "DMT Diamond Mini-Sharp Keyring Sharpener, Fine"  to touch up the blades when they stop cutting as cleanly as I might prefer.
